# sitk.GetArrayFromImage returns empty numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, simpleitk

I am working with 3D MR image data. In order to calculate the histogram, I converted from sitk.Image to an numpy arrray of dimension 3. While I am able to display each axial slice using matplotlib, the numpy array is completely empty in all three dimensions. 
Can someone explain what is going on?

```
import numpy as np
import SimpleITK as sitk
from myshow import myshow

img = sitk.ReadImage("mri.hdr")
nda = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(img)
myshow(img)
print nda
```

Output:

```
[[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  ..., 
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  ..., 
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  ..., 
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

 ..., 
 [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  ..., 
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  ..., 
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  ..., 
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]]
```

NOTES:

- myshow.py (https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/SimpleITK-Notebooks/blob/master/Python/myshow.py)
- myshow.py visualizes a slice of img by using matplotlib
- MR image data is in hdr/img (analyze) format.

Comment: Can you please post a sample of your code, so that we can follow your logic

Comment: Edited! I'm fairly new to coding and stackoverflow. Please excuse me if I'm not presenting my question clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fine. The data is there it's just that the print function is showing data from the beginning of the array (it's large). If you print the data for a specific pixel which has content you'll see a valid value:

`print nda[200,56,87]`

The indexes are assumed to be in the valid range.